# Is there any way of defining interfaces in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, interface, abstraction

I know, there is not any built-in support for abstraction in JavaScript. Is there any way of defining interfaces in Javascript?

Answer (score 1):

If you are after class-based object-orientation with interfaces, static structural typing and plain JavaScript at runtime, you might be interested in the TypeScript project

Some of the features are coming to the next major version of JavaScript but it offers interfaces that are used at design/compile time - although they are erased in the output JavaScript.

http://typescriptlang.org/